# R equivalent of Stata's 'summarize'?

Tags: r, stata, apply

In Stata, `summarize` prints a brief statistical summary of all variables in the current workspace. In R, `summary(<myvariable>)` does something similar for a particular `<myvariable>`.

**Q:** In R, how should I print a statistical summary of ALL relevant variables in my workspace?

I tried:

```
x <- runif(4)
y <- runif(4)
z <- runif(3)
w <- matrix(runif(4), nrow = 2)

sapply(ls(), function(i) {if (class(get(i)) == "numeric") summary(get(i))})
```

which gets close to what I want. But it still prints

```
$w
NULL
...
```

which is undesirable. Also, this code throws an error when there's a variable of type closure in my workspace...

I feel like I'm going off into the weeds here. There must be a simpler, straightforward way of more-or-less replicating Stata's `summarize` in R, right?

Comment: You can put the variables in a data frame `d <- data.frame(x, y, z, w)` and then do `summary(d)`

Comment: @konvas - a `list` would be preferable over a `data.frame` - maybe something like: `lapply(mget(ls()), function(x) if(is.function(x)) "function" else summary(x) )`

Comment: @thelatemail yes fair enough my solution is no good when the lengths of the vectors are different. Anyway what I meant to say is that the idea in R is that good practice is to store your variables in "objects" (like data frames and lists) unlike in Stata where they are part of the data set (I guess an equivalent of attaching a data frame in R although I don't know Stata really). So I think it's best for a new R user, who is used to Stata, to avoid things like `mget(ls())` because they should not really be used that often... So I would reformulate this to `lapply(list(x, y, z), summary)`

Comment: @konvas - I agree that you should store *related* items in a structure, but not necessarily everything in one structure. My workspace at the moment has a bunch of lists/data.frames, some lone vectors storing relevant variable names, a couple of functions etc. If you want to get a snapshot of everything you're working with, I don't see a big problem with using get or mget. But yes, it's not a substitute for collecting related items together, as you should do.

Comment: @thelatemail: You're right. I really would like a method to summarize data varying in type and length in the current workspace. I like your function. It definitely improves upon mine.

Comment: @thelatemail: if you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `methods` to determine which variable types work with `summary`

```
summary.methods = methods(summary)
check.method <- function(x){ 
  any(grepl(paste0('^summary\\.',class(x)[1],'$'),summary.methods))
}
lapply(ls(), function(z,envir = .GlobalEnv) {
 obj = get(z)
 if (class(obj) %in% c('list','data.frame')
    Recall(names(obj),as.environment(obj))
 else if (check.method(obj))
  print(summary(obj))
 else
  print(paste0("No summary for: ",z))
})
```

You may want to change this depending on how much data you have, but it should work.

Added some recursion for list/data frames.

If you want to get it to work with lists and individual data frame columns, I would check for those classes and use `as.environment` to get variables from the list/frame.  I can show you a more explicit way of doing this later if you like.

Comment: I like this. Clever function. But this won't produce summaries for vectors. Not sure if that's a quick fix or indicative of a deeper issue in this method of yours.

Comment: I added some recursion so you can go through elements of lists/data frames.